# Sprite not displaying

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm facing a problem in my scene i drop a object ball in hierarchy and arrange its position in center. But it's not showing that ball in `Scene` and `Game` tab it only shows its circle collider radius like this:

[image]

But when I untick and then tick again back to a component `sprite renderer` then it's show that object in `Scene` and `Game` tab like this:

[image]

Comment: My bad for the answer, didn't read it well enough !

Comment: @PawełMarecki position z axis is set it to -10

Comment: try to set the "Order in Layer" to a higher value then the gray background.

Comment: sometimes a restart of unity perform miracles

Comment: Try to disable the Canvas and see if the problem goes away if it does, you might want a different Sorting Layer for your Canvas. Other than that, check your camera settings, type of camera and in particular the z-axis of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your material. Possibly this material have selected not-existed shader.
2. Check Sorting layer. It must be higher than background Sorting layer